# Idempotent modifiers in C#

Tags: c#, csc

I noticed that if I write something like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const const const bool flag = true;
}
```

The compiler doesn't warn me of the multiple `const`s. So this seems to mimic C modifiers, as they are idempotent.

However, if I write:

```
private readonly readonly int a;
```

The compiler *does* warn me of the duplicated `readonly`.

So what's going on here? Are modifiers idempotent or not?

---

<sup>csc version 1.0.0.50618</sup>

Comment: That the first line compiles is a bug in whichever compiler you're using - which you haven't told us. It doesn't compile with Roslyn...

Comment: I'm not sure I see what your examples have to do with being idempotent.

Comment: This doesn't compile with C#5 either.

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 gives out an error as well.

Comment: @JonSkeet It doesn't compile if you try to put it as field. It does compile inside a method `static void Main(string[] args) { const const const bool flag = true; }`

Comment: @JakubLortz: Nope, still creates an error (`Type expected`) in VS2010.

Comment: As @JakubLortz points out, this WILL compile with Roslyn only if it's in a method.

Comment: Monodevelop doesn't allow it either (even in static method)

Comment: @JakubLortz: Ah, thanks for that. This is why short but *complete* examples are important. Will double check that it's invalid according to the spec, but it does look like it's just a compiler bug.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler This really didn't need the Visual Studio tag adding, please don't suggest edits that add nothing to the question.

Comment: @DavidG uh yeah it did. It's only relevant to VS 2015.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler No, it applies only to C# version 6, it's nothing to do with the version of Visual Studio. I could have written that code with Notepad/Sublime and compiled it that way.

Comment: `C# version 6`

which you only get with Visual Studio 2015. Mono doesn't show the same problem, and the .NET compiler (roslyn) is bundled with Visual Studio. Also the amount of people that would do what you just described can probably be counted on one hand for the entire world, which means for most people this is only relevant if they use Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler That handful of people are the most likely to actually try to repeat a `const` qualifier multiple times on a local variable. =) Or to care when it actually succeeds to compile.

Comment: hm, you may have a point there. @jpmc26

Answer (score 69, accepted):

It's a bug in the compiler - at least in Roslyn version 1.0.0.50618. From section 8.5.2 of the C# 5 specification:

> A *local-constant-declaration* declares one or more local constants.
>
> *local-constant-declaration*:
>      `const` *type* *constant-declarators*
>
> *constant-declarators*:
>     *constant-declarator*
>     *constant-declarators*   `,`   *constant-declarator*
>
> *constant-declarator*:
>     *identifier*   `=`   *constant-expression*

As you can see, that grammar doesn't allow for `const const const bool flag = true;`.

I've filed a [bug against Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/6761) so that it can get fixed.

Comment: This [pull request](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/6929) looks to be the fix.